# KeyboardState in XNA c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna-4.0

Hello I have some trouble in XNA, here my code 
I make a array with a length of 4

```cs
//Initialize
Keyboard oldState = Keyboard.GetState();
int index = 0;

//Update
KeyboardState currentState = Keyboard.GetState();
if (index != 0 && ((currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z) || currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        && ((!oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z)) || (!oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up)))))
        {
            index = index - 1;
        }
        else if (index < menuArray.Length && ((currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S) || currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        && ((!oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S)) || (!oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down)))))
        {
            index = index + 1;
        }
oldState = currentState;
if (index == 0)
    //put the texture here
if (index == 1)
    //put the texture here
if (index == 2)
    // put the texture here
if (index == 3)
    // put the texture here
```

My main issue is when I press Up/Z or Down/S ,the cursor will jump from 0 at 3 or 3 at 0 if i didn't press slightly 
Can you help me to solve that please ?

Comment: You are overwitting the oldstate variable. So both variables will always equal each other.  Also you need to remember tht this portion of code is run every time it gets called which is normally about 60 fps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the 'if' statement boolean logic (and nothing to do with overwriting oldState).

Consider this case:

index = 0

S is pressed down. We're trying to increase the index.

For the index to be incremented, the oldState key S has to be up OR the oldState key Down has to be up.

Notice the OR, this is the problem. Even if on the next frame, the oldState S is NOT up, the Down key is still up, so the OR statement will always return true unless both keys are pressed at the same time. Right now the index is increased every frame (very fast), while the S button is pressed. The easiest fix is to change the OR between the oldState S and Down to an AND.

```
!oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S) && !oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down)
```

and

```
!oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z) && (!oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up)
```

You can also use IsKeyUp() for clarity.

```
oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.S)) && oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Down)
```